# Disable visual bell animation in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, animation

The title says everything, how can I disable the visual bell animation in Lion?

It is annoying and useless, visual bell should be fast, not fancy!

I don't want to disable the visual bell, just the fadin/fadeout animation.

Comment: _What_ visual bell animation? All I see is a sudden change in the brightness of the window, followed by a fade back to normal. The fade takes less than a second, and is not at all annoying to me. What do you see? Dancing bunnies?

Comment: That fade back is the annoying thing, which is not necessary at all. And it is slow on a big display.

Comment: Terminal's visual bell is modeled on the system-wide visual bell available via **System Preferences > Universal Access > Hearing > Flash the screen when an alert sound occurs**. How do they compare to you? Terminal's should not take longer than that. If you're having a performance issue, it's worth investigating. How big is your terminal display usually? What sort of Mac hardware are you using? Is your terminal window translucent or opaque? Is the animation noticeably slow when the terminal window is very small?

Comment: If the performance of the visual bell is an issue, or if you would like a preference for a different visualization (e.g., prior to Lion, it merely inverted the screen colors 100% and then back, but many people disliked it because it was so harsh), please let Apple know using the feedback website http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html or by filing a bug report (requires a free developer account) https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/

Comment: I would like to change the behavior of the Terminal, not the whole system. Changing the Universal Access would do a different thing.

Comment: I reported bugs and ideas to Apple multiple times but I've never got any response or answer from them. Maybe I'll do that again, but I don't think this will fix my problem.

Comment: I just switched from Snow Leopard to Yosemite (I consider it a downgrade in some respects--I'm glad I waited so long) and find the new fading visual bell annoying not because it's slow, but because it's barely noticeable.  A visual bell *should* be harsh.  I'll add my feedback.

Comment: After using Yosemite for a week longer, I'm even more annoyed at the "visual bell".  It's barely noticeable.  The same effect is *very* noticeable when applied to the entire screen, but it's inadequate in a terminal window.  It really doesn't qualify as a visual bell per se.  Apple has effectively removed this standard feature of terminal applications.  OS X Terminal was a great application.  I haven't used any other terminal application for years.  Now I'm thinking about alternatives.

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to the "Terminal" menu
2. Select "Preferences"
3. Select "Settings" at the top
4. Select "Advanced" at the right
5. Uncheck "Visual Bell"

[image: Terminal preferences - Settings - Advanced]

Comment: No, I don't want to disable it. I want to disable the _animation_

Comment: Guys, seriously? Upvoting an answer which is not solving the question?